# WCF naming conventions for extending methods

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a method exposed as an OperationContract for my WCF service that i would like to rework.  The previous programmer had written something like:

```
public ReportResultObject GetReport(string stringContainingParameters)
```

I would like to have a method that is something more like this:

```
public ReportResultObject GetReport(int[] someIds, bool includeAdditionalInformation)
```

Since WCF doesnt allow for overloaded methods without specifying the Name attribute in the OperationContract, and I dont want to break current clients, is there a naming convention for situations like this?  Something like GetReportV2 or GetReportHeyUseMeInstead ?

Comment: What's wrong with the Name in Contract attribute?

Comment: Nothing really, except i was hoping there was a way for a programmer, regardless if they were going off the WSDL or just using the ChannelFactory method, to be able to distinguish from a method only used in older clients, and one that should be used in the new clients.

Answer (score 6):

By doing the same thing again you're just setting yourself up for the same "mess" when you need to add another parameter. I would strongly suggest that you look at having a single parameter which is a data contract;

```
public ReportResultObject GetReportTheSuperDooperWay(
    GetReportParameters parameters)
```

What does this give you? Well

```
[DataContract]
public class GetReportParameters
{
 [DataMember(IsRequired=false)]
 public string parameters;

 [DataMember(IsRequired=false)]
 public int[] someIds;

 [DataMember(IsRequired=false)]
 bool includeAdditionalInformation
}
```

So because each field is optional you can add new fields without breaking existing clients. This is a rather simplistic example, as you'll also want to implement [IExtensibleDataObject](http://blogs.msdn.com/craigmcmurtry/archive/2006/07/23/676104.aspx) too and you should be versioning via namespaces at both the [service](http://www.dasblonde.net/PermaLink,guid,a0b48932-4b7d-4d7b-9886-e7d0764d8908.aspx) and [data](http://www.dasblonde.net/PermaLink,guid,a0b48932-4b7d-4d7b-9886-e7d0764d8908.aspx) contract levels.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with something that made sense, making it more likely that people would recognise it and use it appropriately.

```
public ReportResultObject GetReportWithAdditionalInformation(...)
```

might be a bit too much though!

I'd certainly avoid `GetReportV2` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new operationalcontract and add a namespace to it.  Then have your clients using the new contract call it by the way of the namespace. This will simulate versioning.

Answer (score 0):

If your WCF service is RESTful, does it matter if `bool includeAdditionalInformation` is passed or not?

Comment: It does use REST in some instances, but all other protocols (tcp, ipc and ws HTTP) will be used as well.